# node - mysql query that takes a few minutes repeating itself after a few minutes before finishing the original query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angularjs, express

I am building an app with angular and node js. 
I have a very big query (insert query) that inserts something like 30,000 rows which for some reason takes a few minutes (i suppose its ok).

this is my query:

```
this.createCourts = function (req, res, next){
  console.log("entered creation courts");
      connection.query('CALL filldates("' + 
        req.body['startDate'] + '","' +
        req.body['endDate'] + '","' +
        req.body['numOfCourts'] + '","' +
        req.body['duration'] + '","' +
        req.body['sundayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['mondayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['tuesdayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['wednesdayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['thursdayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['fridayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['saturdayOpen'] + '","' +
        req.body['sundayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['mondayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['tuesdayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['wednesdayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['thursdayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['fridayClose'] + '","' +
        req.body['saturdayClose'] +
        '");', function(err, result, fields){

        if (err){
          console.log("error is" + err);
          return res.send(500, "fail");              
        }
        else{
          console.log("finsihed");
          return res.send(200);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

my ui will click a button which will trigger a service like this:

```
  CourtsService.createCourts.save({}, 
    {"startDate": dateService.Date_toYMD($scope.startDate), 
    "endDate": dateService.Date_toYMD($scope.endDate), 
    "numOfCourts": $scope.numOfCourts, 
    "duration": $scope.duration, 
    "sundayOpen": $scope.sundayOpen.hour, 
    "mondayOpen": $scope.mondayOpen.hour, 
    "tuesdayOpen": $scope.tuesdayOpen.hour, 
    "wednesdayOpen": $scope.wednesdayOpen.hour, 
    "thursdayOpen": $scope.thursdayOpen.hour, 
    "fridayOpen": $scope.fridayOpen.hour, 
    "saturdayOpen": $scope.saturdayOpen.hour, 
    "sundayClose": $scope.sundayClose.hour,
    "mondayClose": $scope.mondayClose.hour,
    "tuesdayClose": $scope.tuesdayClose.hour,
    "wednesdayClose": $scope.wednesdayClose.hour,
    "thursdayClose": $scope.thursdayClose.hour,
    "fridayClose": $scope.fridayClose.hour,
    "saturdayClose": $scope.saturdayClose.hour},
     function(data){
      $scope.showSearching = false;
      $dialog.messageBox("success", btns).open();
  }, function(err){
      $scope.showSearching = false;
      $dialog.messageBox("fail", err.data, btns).open();
  });
```

I added this row on the first line of the function that will actually do the query(its in the code up here)
 console.log("entered creation courts");

My problem is that because the query runs for a few minutes (may be 10 minutes), it seems as if my function is being called again and again because I can see in my console the line
"entered creation courts" approximately every 1 minute and this is ofcourse not something i wish to be happening.

I don't know what triggers the createCourts function again and again.

maybe it is because the UI goes into time out and thus triggers the service again if an answer hasn't been received after 1 minutes (or something close to that). and if this is the reason how do  I tell the service to just wait for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider async api: on the server handler immediately respond with HTTP 200 and some id, and there is another endpoint to check if insert command with id finished.

Be aware that your code prone to sql injection attack. Better approach:

```
var params = req.body; // you may want to filter names explicitly here
connection.query('CALL filldates(?,?,?,?,...)', params, function(err, result, fields){
    if (err){
      console.log("error is" + err);
      return res.send(500, "fail");              
    }
    else{
      console.log("finsihed");
      return res.send(200);
    }
});
```

This would escape all dangerous chars on client before sending query, or use prepared statements with [mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) to send query intdependent of parameters:

```
var params = req.body; // you may want to filter names explicitly here
connection.execute('CALL filldates(?,?,?,?,...)', params, function(err, result, fields){
    if (err){
      console.log("error is" + err);
      return res.send(500, "fail");              
    }
    else{
      console.log("finsihed");
      return res.send(200);
    }
});
```

'few minutes' IMHO is too much, in my benchmarks I have insert rate around 10k rows / second. Try replace inert calls with generation of large insert query text and test with console client. If it still takes few minutes then problem isn't in node land, you need to optimize your database.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i didn't understand what this line means:"and there is another endpoint to check if insert command with id finished."

and what is "generation of large insesrt query text"?

thanks again.

Comment: second question - instead of doing large number of 'insert' requiests, try to generate one big sql string with all inserts, save it to local file and measure how much time it takes to do `cat myinserts.sql | mysql`

Comment: i just surronded this function inside a transaction, and now it takes only 5 seconds. perfect thanks :)